# Menu border and image highlight on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to accomplish a menu where the first link is highlighted with a border-bottom on page load.
There's an image following the mouse on hover on each link in the menu.

Now I've managed to get the border-bottom work on page load, but I'd like to get the first image to show as well. My jQuery skills are extremely limited, so I don't think the coding is very tidy in general.

I'd also love to make the border disappear (fade out/transition) when the user has hovered over an item (now the last hovered item is still underlined when mouse is somewhere else).

```js
$(".menu li a").hover(function() {
  $('.menu li a').removeClass('one');
  $(this).addClass('one');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').mousemove(function(e) {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.stop(1, 1).show();
    $img.offset({
      top: e.pageY - 150,
      left: e.pageX + 100
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.hide();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.two').mousemove(function(e) {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.stop(1, 1).show();
    $img.offset({
      top: e.pageY - 150,
      left: e.pageX + 100
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.hide();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.three').mousemove(function(e) {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.stop(1, 1).show();
    $img.offset({
      top: e.pageY - 150,
      left: e.pageX + 100
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $img = $("#" + $(this).data('image-id'))
    $img.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.one {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid lightgreen;
}

img.mouse-hovered {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <img id="img-one" src="http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg" class="mouse-hovered">
    <a href="#" class="one" data-image-id="img-one">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img id="img-two" src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/36522-Tabby-kitten-white-background.jpg" class="mouse-hovered">
    <a href="#" class="two" data-image-id="img-two">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img id="img-three" src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/11406-Ginger-kitten-rolling-on-its-back-white-background.jpg" class="mouse-hovered">
    <a href="#" class="three" data-image-id="img-three">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d7oj35wm/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the following code within the `$(document).ready()` function to load the first image without hovering.

You will need to apply CSS styling to position the image correctly.

```js
    
// Load initial image
$("#" + $('.one').data('image-id')).stop(1, 1).show();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! The only issue with that is that I need to hover over the .one image first to make it disappear. If I hover any of the other two first the .one image stays where it is. Any way to go around this?